# Redux toolkit Could not find react-redux context value - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit

I am this weird issue with React-native app, I am creating a React-native project and using Redux-toolkit for state management. Somehow it's keep giving me this error.

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

I have followed the documentation and did everything correctly. I have looked for similar problems on stackoverflow but still not luck.

here is my app.tsx

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react'
import { store, persistor, useAppSelector } from '@/Store'
import ApplicationNavigator from '@/Navigators/Application'
import './Translations'
import { selectTheme } from './Store/reducers/Theme'
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper'

const App = () => {
  const theme = useAppSelector(selectTheme)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          {/**
           * PersistGate delays the rendering of the app's UI until the persisted state has been retrieved
           * and saved to redux.
           * The `loading` prop can be `null` or any react instance to show during loading (e.g. a splash screen),
           * for example `loading={<SplashScreen />}`.
           * @see https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md
           */}
          <ApplicationNavigator />
        </PaperProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

as you can see i have wrapped my app with **Provider** with store.

ApplicationNavigator:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { navigationRef } from './utils'
import MainNavigator from './Main'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// @refresh reset
const ApplicationNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <StatusBar />
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Main"
            component={MainNavigator}
            options={{
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default ApplicationNavigator
```

The store and reducer have the basic boilerplate from @redux-toolkit.

Comment: no luck still same issue

Answer (score 1):

You're using your `useAppSelector` in the `App` component which is **not** wrapped in the `Provider`. You're wrapping the children of `App` in the Provider.

You can fix this by wrapping your `App` component inside the `Provider`. Something like this could work.

```js
// instead of
// export default App

const withProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default withProvider;
```